# Create a Shipment Order in ups.com through api

Tags: php, api, ups

I have the api key and all the login credentials of ups.com
I want to create shipment after my order is successfully 
placed in my website through api call,I have read the documentation
but I am not getting the specific code or call.
any help is welcomed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find some example code in the UPS Developer Kit portal (https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit). Login with your UPS username and password then download the desired compressed file (e.g.: Rating, Shipping, etc.). See picture below.

[image: UPS Developer Kit Portal]

Inside those compressed files you will find the **web services** and **XML API's** documentation and some code samples written in **Java**, **C#**, **Perl** and **PHP**.

Best!